# React not rendering components while looping through array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

So I basically have an array of JSON objects that I'm trying to loop through and render on the screen however It doesn't seem to be working and React offers no errors whatsoever

```js
let quizCards = [];
    fetch("/api/get-all-quiz")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((JSONResponse) => {
            console.log(JSONResponse["message"][0].name);
            for (let i = 0; i <= JSONResponse["message"].length + 3; i++) {
                quizCards.push(
                    <Card w="200%" h="100%">
                        <Flex>
                            <Flex direction={"column"}>
                                <Text>Hello</Text>
                            </Flex>
                        </Flex>
                    </Card>
                );
            }
        });
```

Here, `JSONResponse['message']` is the array of objects, However the Card Component doesn't seem to be getting rendered

I have already added `{quizCards}` where I would like for them to be displayed, however it doesn't seem to work, also when I manually added a card (without looping over the JSON object) it seemed to work, but I'd like for that to be done dynamically

Comment: Do not put components in state, just put the API response in state and render from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't keep components inside a state. Instead of using a state and loading the values as part of a side effect you could also refactor the fetch statement into a separate lazy component.

```
const Lazy: React.FC = React.lazy(() => {
    return fetch("/api/get-all-quiz")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((JSONResponse) => {
            const quizCards = [];
            for (let i = 0; i <= JSONResponse["message"].length + 3; i++) {
                quizCards.push(
                    <Card w="200%" h="100%">
                        <Flex>
                            <Flex direction="column">
                                <Text>Hello</Text>
                            </Flex>
                        </Flex>
                    </Card>
                );
            }
            return {default: () => (<>{quizCards}</>)}
        })
        .catch((error) => ({default: () => (<>{error}</>)}));
});
```

And then use it with Suspense, where you can define what to show while awaiting the request response.

```
const Parent: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <Lazy />
        </React.Suspense>
    )
}
```

Comment: Or one could use a data-fetching hook like swr, etc., but the main point is: no components in state!